# Windows 10 universal app not working on windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have been working on a universal windows 10 app but when I'am testing it on my phone it is stuck on the splash screen. The app does work great on the computer.
is this a bug in the software or my app?

I'am running windows 10 version build 10130
Latest visual studio 2015

phone is:
Lumia 635
Windows phone version 10.0.10149.0

Edit: This is what my output also when starting the app it does go all the way through the OnLaunched in app.xaml.cs without any problems.

> 'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0_1.0.22816.1_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UAP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8174a553-5131-4f3c-a81e-695e46bec080VS.Debug_ARM.Merien\MercadoAppx.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UAP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8174a553-5131-4f3c-a81e-695e46bec080VS.Debug_ARM.Merien\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UAP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8174a553-5131-4f3c-a81e-695e46bec080VS.Debug_ARM.Merien\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
>   'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UAP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8174a553-5131-4f3c-a81e-695e46bec080VS.Debug_ARM.Merien\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UAP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8174a553-5131-4f3c-a81e-695e46bec080VS.Debug_ARM.Merien\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UAP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8174a553-5131-4f3c-a81e-695e46bec080VS.Debug_ARM.Merien\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UAP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8174a553-5131-4f3c-a81e-695e46bec080VS.Debug_ARM.Merien\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UAP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8174a553-5131-4f3c-a81e-695e46bec080VS.Debug_ARM.Merien\Internal.Uri.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MercadoAppx.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UAP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8174a553-5131-4f3c-a81e-695e46bec080VS.Debug_ARM.Merien\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Thank you

Comment: Without any more information about where it is stuck in the loading process it is impossibel to tell.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know any way to debug this. everything is loading fine on the output screen but it is just stuck on the splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing with moving one for one pages to another project I found out the problem was in my app.xaml.cs . And the way I called my hamburger shell.
This question can now be closed thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need update to build 136. Downgrade to 8.1 and upgrade to 10136

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but in my case I had renamed the namespace for my App class but had forgotten to rename it in the App.xaml file. No compile errors, just stuck on the splash screen.